# How can I jump from one end of a coaster to the other while building?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

In RollerCoaster Tycoon, when I'm building a roller coaster, sometimes I screw up somewhere in the middle and have to bulldoze to fix it.

When I bulldoze to create a break in the track, I often find that I have to fix the track *before* the break, then click the little "next section" arrow dozens of times to get all the way around to the track section *after* the break and fix it as well.

Is there some way, when constructing a roller coaster with a break in the track, that I can quickly jump from one side of the break to the other without having to click the arrows to go all the way around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realized today (it was in the status bar, but it wasn't very overt) that I can right-click on any section of track to go to that section.  This is basically what I needed.